# android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line #11

Tags: android

(Sorry for my bad english) I get this error when try to run my project

```
03-01 18:46:24.242: E/AndroidRuntime(25937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 18:46:24.242: E/AndroidRuntime(25937): Process: com.example.assignment_mob201, PID: 25937
03-01 18:46:24.242: E/AndroidRuntime(25937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.assignment_mob201/com.example.assignment_mob201.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-01 18:46:24.242: E/AndroidRuntime(25937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
03-01 18:46:24.242: E/AndroidRuntime(25937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2095)
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.assignment_mob201"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <service android:name=".RssService" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="Đăng nhập Facebook" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB76ayOTN2CP8wvizN3cIowbEYXXj5lytY" />
```

My MapsActivity.java

```
package com.example.assignment_mob201;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    }
}
```

My activity_maps.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="tranduythanh.com.learngooglemap.MainActivity" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I put MapsActivity in a tabhost and show it in MainActivity, can it get error because of this ? (Sorry for my bad English T_T )

Comment: you didn't define your `MapsActivity` in your `AndroidManifest`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your line,

`public class MapsActivity extends Activity {`

with

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity{
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file

Comment: i use eclipse ide ==!

Answer (score 0):

first of all extend your MapsActivity by **FragmentActivity** not by **Activity**.

And than Define Your MapsActivity in AndroidManifest.xml